# How to remove empty directory recursively in Delphi

Tags: delphi, directory

A parent directory D:\AAA  has 2 child empty Directory D:\AAA\BB1 and D:\AAA\BB2
my requirement is how to remove empty Directory recursively.
Here are two function found on internet as below :
//remove empty Directory recursively

```
function RemoveEmptyDirectory(path: string) : Boolean;
var
  MySearch: TSearchRec;
  Ended: Boolean;
begin
  if FindFirst(path + '\*.*', faDirectory, MySearch) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      if ((MySearch.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory) and
        (MySearch.Name[1] <> '.') then
      begin
        if DirectoryIsEmpty(path + '\' + MySearch.Name) then
          TDirectory.Delete(path + '\' + MySearch.Name)
        else
        begin
          RemoveEmptyDirectory(path + '\' + MySearch.Name);
          if DirectoryIsEmpty(path + '\' + MySearch.Name) then
            RemoveEmptyDirectory(path + '\' + MySearch.Name);
        end;
      end;
    until FindNext(MySearch) <> 0;
    FindClose(MySearch);
  end;
end;
```

// check directory is empty or not

```
function DirectoryIsEmpty(Directory: string): Boolean;
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  FindFirst(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Directory) + '*', faAnyFile, SR);
  for i := 1 to 2 do
    if (SR.Name = '.') or (SR.Name = '..') then
      Result := FindNext(SR) <> 0;
  FindClose(SR);
end;
```

My problem is here : at first run function RemoveEmptyDirectory will found D:\AAA is not empty, then will run send round (recursively way),
After remove 2 child directory D:\AAA\BB1 and D:\AAA\BB2, the parent will become an empty Directory,
Back to first round place the function DirectoryIsEmpty report the parent is not an empty directory!!!!
Why !!!!
Is windows system still not change the directory state ???

So, is there any good suggestion that could meet my requirement.

Comment: What happens if your algorithm encounters a directory named ".hidden" ? (ie. don't simply check if first character is '.' - check if entire name is '.' or '..')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **never check** `D:\AAA` itself.

Just make checking and deletion in the end:

```
function RemoveEmptyDirectory(path: string) : Boolean;
var
  MySearch: TSearchRec;
  Ended: Boolean;
begin
  if FindFirst(path + '\*.*', faDirectory, MySearch) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      if ((MySearch.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory) and
        (MySearch.Name[1] <> '.') then
      begin
        if DirectoryIsEmpty(path + '\' + MySearch.Name) then
          TDirectory.Delete(path + '\' + MySearch.Name)
        else
        begin
          RemoveEmptyDirectory(path + '\' + MySearch.Name);
          if DirectoryIsEmpty(path + '\' + MySearch.Name) then
            RemoveEmptyDirectory(path + '\' + MySearch.Name);
        end;
      end;
    until FindNext(MySearch) <> 0;
    FindClose(MySearch);
  end;

  if DirectoryIsEmpty(path) then
    TDirectory.Delete(path);

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`TDirectory`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory) as

```
TDirectory.Delete('D:\AAA', True);
```

If you need to check if the directories are empty or not, you can use `TDirectory.GetDirectories()` as

```
Var
  S: string;
begin
  for S in TDirectory.GetDirectories('D:\AAA', '*', TSearchOption.soAllDirectories) do
    begin
      if TDirectory.IsEmpty(S) then
        TDirectory.Delete(S);
    end;
  If TDirectory.IsEmpty('D:\AAA') then
    TDirectory.Delete('D:\AAA');
```

Comment: TDirectory.Delete removes also non-emtpy dirs with files

Comment: @MBo Yup, looking to the body of the question, I guess that's what the OP want to. If not, then he can use `GetDirectories()` and check if it's empty or not.

Comment: I try to use TDirectory.IsEmpty to replace Function DirectoryIsEmpty, but not thing change, the TDirectory.IsEmpty report the parent directory is not empty , after the 2 child is removed. Is this part cause by recursive way function let the windows system did change the parent directory to empty state ?

Comment: ` the TDirectory.IsEmpty report the parent directory is not empty` - it can't,  because it does not check parent dir in your code.

Comment: @MBo  look at function RemoveEmptyDirectory ......
let us trace the loop........
at the line : if  DirectoryIsEmpty(path + '\' + MySearch.Name) then ===> here MySearch.Name= 'D:\AAA', it is the parent directory, 
and it is not an empty directory, then program will jump to the line : RemoveEmptyDirectory(path + '\' + MySearch.Name), here is the point to recursive part, then after  2 empty child directory deleted, so at this moment the parent directory should be empty now,

Comment: next step will go back to the line : if DirectoryIsEmpty(path + '\' + MySearch.Name) then
RemoveEmptyDirectory(path + '\' + MySearch.Name);
here  MySearch.Name =  'D:\AAA' , so here  DirectoryIsEmpty(path + '\' + MySearch.Name) check parent directory.

Comment: MySearch.Name never becomes   'D:\AAA'. You can dump all MySearch.Name to Memo. Code from my answer deletes all directories including AAA. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simple and straightforward and should do fine if top performance is not crucial:

```
procedure RemoveEmptyDirs;
var
  i,Removed:integer;
  Arr:TStringDynArray;
const
  TargedDir = 'C:\BunchOfDirs\';
begin
  Arr := TDirectory.GetDirectories(TargedDir,'*',TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
  Repeat
    Removed := 0;
    For i := High(Arr) downto Low(Arr) do begin
      If TDirectory.IsEmpty(Arr[i]) then begin
        TDirectory.Delete(Arr[i]);
        System.Delete(Arr,i,1);
        Inc(Removed);
      end;
    end;
  Until Removed = 0;
end;
```